# SQLite take N rows per each group

Tags: sqlite, random, limit-per-group

I have an SQLite table similar to the following:

```
| A | B |
_________
| e | 5 |
| f | 7 |
| a | 5 |
| n | 7 |
| g | 5 |
| d | 7 |
| i | 5 |
| j | 5 |
| e | 7 |
| v | 7 |
```

How can I retrieve three random rows with value `5` in column `B` and three random rows with value `7`? I don't know values in `B`, neither values`5` ad `7`. *I want 3 random rows for each different value in `B`.* Result may be not grouped by column `B` values. It could be something like:

```
| A | B |
_________
| e | 5 |
| g | 5 |
| e | 7 |
| v | 7 |
| j | 5 |
| f | 7 |
```

Comment: When you say “random” do you mean that you’ll get a different selection of rows each time, dictated by fair chance? Or do you merely mean you don’t care which rows are fetched, so that the query could return the same results over and over?

Comment: the second one could also work, but the first one would be better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following almost does what you want:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.rowid in (select t2.rowid
                  from t t2
                  where t2.b = t.b
                  order by random()
                  limit 3
                 );
```

Alas, the subquery will be run for every row, so this is only approximate because the random number generator changes values on each execution.

One solution is to use a temporary table to store a random number for each row, which can then be used for sorting.  Unfortunately, a CTE doesn't seem to do the trick, because these are re-evaluated on each reference.

After some thought, I think a temporary table might be the only solution:

```
drop table if exists tempt;

create temporary table tempt as 
    select t.*, random() as rand
    from t;

select t.*
from tempt t
where t.rowid in (select t2.rowid
                  from tempt t2
                  where t2.b = t.b
                  order by rand
                  limit 3
                 );
```

Comment: `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempt` at the beginning is better

Answer (score 1):

You can use the hidden RowID column to get three rows per B value as follows:

```
 SELECT A, B FROM T T1
    WHERE RowID IN (SELECT RowID FROM T T2 WHERE B = T1.B LIMIT 3);
```

Note that you're likely (but not 100% guaranteed) to get the same three rows each time.  If you want to get random rows at the expense of some performance, you can do:

```
 SELECT A, B FROM T T1
    WHERE RowID IN (SELECT RowID FROM T T2 WHERE B = T1.B ORDER BY random() LIMIT 3);
```

Comment: don't know why, but the second gives me sometimes 4 sometimes 2 and somtimes 3 results per a single value in column `B`, see the ansewr by @gordon linoff